# wordpress pagenavi wrong total number of pages

Tags: php, wordpress

in my wp theme i made the number of posts equal 2 per page(for example), and I have 3 posts, so the first 2 posts must be showed on the 1st page, and the last post on the 2nd page, and total number of pages must be 2 (I guess), but there are 6 pages, and I have no idea why. There is code of my loop and pagination:

```
<?php 
  echo '<div class="news-block">';
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $query = new WP_Query(array('category_name' => 'news', 'showposts' => '2', 'paged' => $paged) );
    if (have_posts() ) :
      while ( have_posts()) : the_post() ;
      echo '<div class="news-column">';
      echo '<div class="news-img column">';
      echo '<div class="news-date">'. get_the_time('j M Y') . '</div>';
      echo '</div>' ;
      echo '<div class="news-content column">';
      echo '<div class="news-title">' . get_the_title() . '</div>';
      echo  the_excerpt() . '</div>';
      echo '</div>';

     endwhile;

      echo '</div>';

      echo '<div class="pagination-list">';
      previous_posts_link('<i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i>'); 
      wp_pagenavi(); 
      next_posts_link('<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>');
      echo '</div>';
  endif;
  wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
```

Comment: Replace your query with this: `$query = new WP_Query(array('category_name' => 'news', 'showposts' => '2', 'paged' => $paged) );` Let me know if that works.

Comment: Wow, unfortunately, it doesn't work, but i've got the reason, the problem is because of the other posts, but not from this category, in my case, it shows me posts from category 'news', but it creates the number of pages for all posts, although, it doesn't show them. So now i need to make it create pages only for 1 category, and how to do it?

Comment: hmmmm...you should be able to get the current category for each page. Hang on. let me check.

Comment: i add some changes above, that makes the result described in my last comment